# Add element to array and print the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

> In `arrays.js`, define two functions, `addElementToBeginningOfArray` and `destructivelyAddElementToBeginningOfArray`. Both functions take two parameters, an array and an element to add to the beginning of the array, and both functions should add the element to the beginning of the array and then return the whole array. The destructive function, `destructivelyAddElementToBeginningOfArray`, should alter the original array that's passed in; `addElementToBeginningOfArray`, on the other hand, should return a new array and not modify the original.

This is my code, but I need to print the array elements:

```
destructivelyAddElementToBeginningOfArray(arry, elementN){
    arry.unshift(elementN)
    return arry
}
```

Comment: You should probably look at ways to ask an effective [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  But it sounds like you are looking for [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Answer (score 0):

You can print output a few different ways, I would go with console.log personally for homework code, unless you have a brief on how it should print. This is a fairly basic question, that you probably could have found an answer to on your own if you knew where to look :). I would point you towards [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) for referencing JS, CSS, and HTML. Hope that helps.

```
destructivelyAddElementToBeginningOfArray(array, elementN){
    array.unshift(elementN)
    return array
}
let result = destructivelyAddElementToBegginingOfArray([1, 2, 3], 4);
// pick one
console.log(result);
document.write(result);
alert(result);
```

Or if you need to illustrate that you are changing inside the function do something like this.

```
destructivelyAddElementToBeginningOfArray(array, elementN){
    array.unshift(elementN)
    console.log(array);
    return;
}
```